# What should I use as validation tool using NestJS and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose, nestjs

Let's say, I am creating application using NestJS. I use MongoDB as a database and mongoose as ODM. So, NestJS has it's own way to validate data - ValidationPipe's. On the other side, there is mongoose built-in ways to validate data that being pushed into DB.
The question is - can I use only NestJS validation or do I need also second-check my data using mongoose validation tools?

Personally, I can't see why should I use additional layer of validation if I already have NestJS validation. But maybe there is best-practice or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Each database validates input data and emits an error if found**. However, you must take into account your schema file. For instance, if you are using Prisma(*It doesn't actually matter*) and you have a User model like below

```
model User {
  id            String          @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email         String          @unique
  password      String
  name          String
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime        @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime        @updatedAt
  
  @@map("user")
}
```

As you can see there is only one optional property "**image**". Whether you pass a value for image property or not, the database will insert the data as a row. On the other hand, **the properties without "?" mark at the end of the type**, will not be stored if you don't pass them and emit an error.

Therefore, if you modeled schema according to your business logic, **you don't need to validate twice** but only add an exception handling like the one below.

```
const user = await this.usersService.findOne('id...')
                   .catch((e) => new NotFoundException({ message: 'No user found.' }))
```